# Does referring to someone as a "rando" mean you didn't know who they were at the end of your interaction with them?

Tags: slang

> I got a message from a rando ...
>
> Some rando walked up to me and said ...

It seems clear to me that the speaker here didn't know who this person was at the beginning of the interaction, when the conversation started.

My question is whether this phrasing is still typical if the speaker discovered who the person was and that they were not a stranger by the end of the conversation.

e.g. "I got a message from a rando about my bike for sale. It turns out they are my long lost brother."

My purpose in asking this question is to better inform a discussion about reasonable interpretations of the use of "rando" and what it implies about if and when new information may have or did not become available.

Comment: *Rando* is the random stranger, often on the internet. What happens later and how soon you marry is another matter.

Comment: Have you looked it up in a dictionary? It's not a precise term, it typically relates to a combination of the person's appearance, behaviour and social status. What does "the speaker discovered who the person was" actually mean - you find they're your long lost brother, or that their name is John and they believe aliens are controlling their thoughts?  "Stranger" isn't a precise term either: would you consider someone you've only just met to be a stranger? It would depend.

Comment: With the word 'stranger', the [for-the-foreseeable-future-]permanence/impermanence of that status is obviously determined by context: [a] 'A complete stranger handed me £20 when I was waiting for the train to Timbuktu. I often wonder who she was.' [b] 'This stranger walked into the meeting, and I disliked him at once. Did my attytude change over the coming months as I got to know him? Reader, I married him.' // Note that 'rando' is slang and often seen as disparaging.

Comment: He was a "random stranger" ***when he walked up to you***. It's irrelevant to that initial statement whether you got to know more about him ***later***.

Comment: @StuartF Reminds me of how a pedo might get around a child being taught "Don't talk to strangers.". They introduce themselves to the child, then explain "You know my name, so I'm not a stranger." Hopefully adults are not susceptible to this.

Comment: Rando is fundamentally a dismissive term. So it's someone that you think would have zero impact on your future.

Comment: Although the question is formulated as a question about the meaning one specific term, *rando*, and was apparently so interpreted by those who voted to close it, the gist of it is not specific to that term. The gist of the question is whether the use of such terms, including the more mainstream *stranger*, is based on what one knew at the time of the events described, or on what one knows now, at the time of speaking. This is a reasonable question to ask, and the answer to it will not be obvious from the dictionary entries for these terms.

Comment: I don't use the word **rando** myself  (it is relatively recent slang) and I am not sure whether it means simply "a stranger" or if it has the nuance "a stranger acting strangely".    Can a "passing stranger" be a rando if they aren't unusual in any way?

Comment: @TimR Yes, in fact acting strangely would mean they are having an effect, and would make them  not a rando. Randos are fungible and nondescript.

Comment: @PhilSweet  So I could be encountering rando after rando after rando and have no recollection whatsoever of having done so. Being a rando is a kind of superpower.  A cloak of rando-ness

Comment: @StuartF "What does "the speaker discovered who the person was" actually mean"? In this case, I intended it to mean that they wouldn't describe the person as a rando at the start of their next interaction.

Comment: @PhilSweet Someone you *still* think would have zero impact on your future, or just someone you thought that about at the point in the story where you called them a rando? You've brought us right back to the crux of the question.

Answer (score 1):

It means who they are is of no importance - they are fungible and nondescript as far as the speaker is concerned. None of their attributes mattered to you, whether you knew them or not.

> My question is whether this phrasing is still typical if the speaker discovered who the person was and that they were not a stranger by the end of the conversation.

As a matter of ordinary social conduct, you wouldn't normally be so dismissive towards friends and family as to call them randos. Randos are John Q. Public who briefly inserted themselves into your awareness uninvited; and who you expended no energy on and cared nothing about.